# App Crashes When the Swipe to Delete feature is used Twice on the same row

Tags: ios, swift

I have one UITableView in this View Controller. When I run the app, and use the swipe to delete function (say on row 3), it deletes the row perfectly the first time. If I add new data to the same row (row 3), and perform the swipe to delete action again, the app crashes, and gives me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. This is a part of my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        toDoList.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        feedTimes = feedTimes - 1
        ft.text = "\(toDoList.count)"
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why this may be happening? 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: How do you add new data to the array?

Comment: I have a UIPickerView with 3 components that shows a bunch of data that can be stored in the array. I essentially select new data from the picker view, and press a button to store that data in the array.
This is the line in my code that does it: 


`toDoList.append(pickerData[0][myPicker.selectedRowInComponent(0)] + ":" + pickerData[1][myPicker.selectedRowInComponent(1)] + " " + pickerData[2][myPicker.selectedRowInComponent(2)])`

Comment: Does it give you no other error? just the crash?

Comment: Yes. It crashes and gives me the "exc_1386_GPFLT" error.

Comment: its crashes some time only if you swipe and delete quickly in my case

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have incorrect values for update. Check them repeatedly.
By the way, in this case, instead of reloadData use:

```
performBatchUpdates {
    deleteRowsAtIndexPaths
    // or
    deleteSections
}
```

relatively to your table structure

Answer (score 1):

Apple in [Inserting and Deleting Rows and Sections](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html) document proposes:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// If row is deleted, remove it from the list.
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        SimpleEditableListAppDelegate *controller = (SimpleEditableListAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [controller removeObjectFromListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

I used to use this approach successfully.